# How do I make it so the lines keep showing new letters instead of getting rid of the already shown letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I am making a hangman game and I have the lines with hidden letters but the problem is when I enter a new letter it re-hides the last.

I want it so I can keep showing more letters if I get it right until the entire word is shown and if a letter that isnt in the word is inputed, nothing should happen at all.

Btw Im using python 3 and no imports so far

Code:

```
#word is selected from a word list so just imagine it is "stuff"
#letter is the letter that the user guesses to see if its in the word or not
def line1():
  try:
    if letter != "a":
      b1 = word.replace("a", "_ ")
    else:
      b1 = word
    if letter != "b":
      b2 = b1.replace("b", "_ ")
    else:
      b2 = b1
    if letter != "c":
      b3 = b2.replace("c", "_ ")
    else:
      b3 = b2
    if letter != "d":
      b4 = b3.replace("d", "_ ")
    else:
      b4 = b3
    if letter != "e":
      b5 = b4.replace("e", "_ ")
    else:
      b5 = b4
    if letter != "f":
      b6 = b5.replace("f", "_ ")
    else:
      b6 = b5
    if letter != "g":
      b7 = b6.replace("g", "_ ")
    else:
      b7 = b6
    if letter != "h":
      b8 = b7.replace("h", "_ ")
    else:
      b8 = b7
    if letter != "i":
      b9 = b8.replace("i", "_ ")
    else:
      b9 = b8
    if letter != "j":
      b10 = b9.replace("j", "_ ")
    else:
      b10 = b9
    if letter != "k":
      b11 = b10.replace("k", "_ ")
    else:
      b11 = b10
    if letter != "l":
      b12 = b11.replace("l", "_ ")
    else:
      b12 = b11
    if letter != "m":
      b13 = b12.replace("m", "_ ")
    else:
      b13 = b12
    if letter != "n":
      b14 = b13.replace("n", "_ ")
    else:
      b14 = b13
    if letter != "o":
      b15 = b14.replace("o", "_ ")
    else:
      b15 = b14
    if letter != "p":
      b16 = b15.replace("p", "_ ")
    else:
      b16 = b15
    if letter != "q":
      b17 = b16.replace("q", "_ ")
    else:
      b17 = b16
    if letter != "r":
      b18 = b17.replace("r", "_ ")
    else:
      b18 = b17
    if letter != "s":
      b19 = b18.replace("s", "_ ")
    else:
      b19 = b18
    if letter != "t":
      b20 = b19.replace("t", "_ ")
    else:
      b20 = b19
    if letter != "u":
      b21 = b20.replace("u", "_ ")
    else:
      b21 = b20
    if letter != "v":
      b22 = b21.replace("v", "_ ")
    else:
      b22 = b21
    if letter != "w":
      b23 = b22.replace("w", "_ ")
    else:
      b23 = b22
    if letter != "x":
      b24 = b23.replace("x", "_ ")
    else:
      b24 = b23
    if letter != "y":
      b25 = b24.replace("y", "_ ")
    else:
      b25 = b24
    if letter != "z":
      b26 = b25.replace("z", "_ ")
    else:
      b26 = b25
    print(b26)
  except ValueError:
    nothing = 1
```

Comment: Can you please add some code to show how you are using `line1` and what is `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplify it first

```
def mask_word(word,guessed_letters=None):
    guessed_letters = guessed_letters or set()
    return ''.join(ltr if ltr in guessed_letters else '_' for ltr in word)

print(mask_word("PIG",set(["I"])) # '_I_'
```

then keep track of guessed letters in a set

```
guessed_letters = set()
word = "PIG"
num_tries = 5 
for i in range(num_tries):
    guessed_letters.add(input("Enter A Letter")[0].upper())
    print(mask_word(word,guessed_letters))
    # once you have guessed all the letters
    if set(word).issubset(guessed_letters):
       print("You WIN!")
       break
else:
    print(f"You Are Out Of Tries!!!! You Lose the word was {word}")
```